# GCC won't detect header files in same directory

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, path

I am trying to compile a bunch of c files but for some reason compiler won't detect the header files which are located in the same exact folder. Here is the error I am getting

```
C:\Users\bz733p\Desktop\EBI20\source\application.c:45:25: fatal error: application.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

Batch file:

```
set COMP_DIR=C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\EBI20\source
set BIN_DIR=C:\Apps\opentoolsuite\runtime\msys\gcc\4.5.1-tdm-x32\bin
set CFLAGS=-g -Wall -m32 

:: Clean 
echo Cleaning directory...
::call clean.bat

:: Start the build

::COMPiling
echo COMPiling files....
for %%i in ("%COMP_DIR%\*.C")do %BIN_DIR%\i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.5.1.exe -c  %CFLAGS% "%%~i" -o "%%~dpni.o" > results.txt
pause
```

I verified that both files are located in the same directory [Files in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBhR.png). This happens for all header files in the directory. I looked into but could not find any solution

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. You should be able to demonstrate it with two files `foo.h` and `foo.c` and a one-line command that invokes the compiler. Include the contents of the two files, the command, and the compile-time output in your question. The issue might be `#include <foo.h>` vs. `#include "foo.h"`, but you haven't shown us any source code.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue, thanks! I managed to solve it by adding `-I%COMP_DIR%` option to CFLAGS.